# How to create a zip file dynamically and download it

Tags: php, laravel

I have the next problem: The user upload files to the server, afther that, the client can download these files (independently) buut, if files is > 2 so, the client can download all files in one .zip file.

So, I don't want to save this .zip file in the server, I just want to create this .zip file and return it to the client when client clicked the "Download zip file" button.

Is it posible?
I have used Zipper library for make zip files with laravel but this library save the file in the server and when I return the file zip to the client this file is not made yet and I get a FileException (the file is not found), I use a while for wait while the file is creating but the process is stoped and Zipper library cannot make the file.

Thank you :)

Comment: Why is it important that the file is not temporarily saved to the server? Sounds like Laravel does basically what you want.

Comment: disk space :O btw, I have made that step (save the zip in server) but when I return these file I have the fileexception because the file is not created yet (1 or 2 seconds afther depends of the file sizes)

Comment: in that `while` loop you just need to verify and wait until `file_exists($myZipFile)`. Also use the `sleep($seconds)` or `usleep($microseconds)` function to decrease the cpu usage. The script is stopped probably because you have a small `max_execution_time` value set in php.ini

Comment: Use this plugin to work with zip archives https://github.com/Chumper/Zipper